# Change iframe src from inside after setting src with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, src, attr

I have an iframe the source of which i'm changing via various buttons using jquery.  For some reason after the iframe source is set i can't seem to change the src attribute from links within it.  The content will change correctly, but not the src attribute.  I need the src to change so i can look for it from the main page to do stuff there.

This is the code from the main page that i'm using to set the src:

```
$('#section').attr('src','music.html');
```

And from within the frame i've tried using regular links, window.location, etc.

Comment: Is the content of the iframe running on the same domain?

Comment: yes it is (trying to change 'music.html' to 'america.html' for example)

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you did should work. Can you show us more code?

Comment: $('#section').attr('src') should give you the updated SRC even if It's not updated on the page itself on runtime.

Comment: not sure what other code to cite specifically that might be affecting it but here's the site: http://dinakelbermanwebdesign.com/dan/  click the teal arc with the record, slides out iframe w/ src attr 'music.html', click first img inside frame (just a regular a tag around img), changes content to 'america.html' but not src attr of iframe.  other arcs will change the src correct per same attr jquery in main site . . .

Comment: I would go for `document.getElementById('section').contentWindow.location.href` to get the URL and forget about the src attribute.